# How to write unicode text to file in python 2 & 3 using same code?

Tags: python, python-unicode, python-2to3

I am trying to write a program that can run through both python 2 & 3. It reads character from website and writes into file. I have already imported `unicode_literals` from __future__.

Straight out trying to write a string that looks like this:

```
txt = u'his$\u2026\n'
```

Will result in UnicodeEncodeError:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The only way to write it to a file in python2 is:

```
fp = open("/tmp/test", "w")
txt2 = txt.encode('utf-8')
fp.write(txt2) # It works
type(txt2) # str - that is why it works
```

However, trying to reuse the same code in python3 is not going to work since in python 3,

```
type(txt2) # is byte type
```

E.g

```
txt.encode('utf-8')
b'his$\xe2\x80\xa6\n'
```

Forcing a `fp.write(txt2)` will throw TypeError:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

So, can`txt = u'his$\u2026\n'` be written in a file using the same code block in both python 2 and 3. (Other than using a wrapper on fp.write)

Comment: Using 'print(txt.encode('utf-8'), file=fp)` is a part-time solution. It will work well in python2. However, it won't work well enough in python3, instead of printing the actual character it will actually print the string literal representation of the bytes. As in, instead of printing his$… python3 will end up with: b'his$\xe2\x80\xa6\n'.

Comment: What do you mean by "mixed string"? I see you've tagged this unicode-normalization; is that an issue here?

Comment: I shouldn't have said mixed string, my bad. The string when printed looks something like this: his$…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You say:

> The only way to write it to a file in python2 is:

```
fp = open("/tmp/test", "w")
txt2 = txt.encode('utf-8')
fp.write(txt2) # It works
```

But that's not true. There are many ways to do it that are better than this. The One Obvious Way To Do It is with [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open). In 3.x, this is the same function as the builtin `open`. In 2.6 and 2.7, it's effectively a backport of the 3.x builtin. This means you get 3.x-style Unicode text files in both versions:

```
fp = io.open("/tmp/test", "w", encoding='utf-8')
fp.write(txt2) # It works
```

If you need compatibility with 2.5 or earlier—or possibly 2.6 and 3.0 (they support `io.open`, but it's very slow in some cases), you can use the older way, [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
fp = codecs.open("/tmp/test", "w", encoding='utf-8')
fp.write(txt2) # It works
```

There are differences between the two under the covers, but most code you write isn't going to be interested in the underlying raw file or the encoder buffer or anything else besides the basic file-like object API, so you can also use `try`/`except ImportError` to fall back to `codecs` if `io` isn't available.

Comment: codecs.open fixed my issue. I ignored io.open since it is too slow in 2.6 and did not much into codecs other than encode/decode. I am marking this as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the file with the `'b'` mode will allow you to use identical code in Python2 and Python3:

```
txt = u'his$\u2026\n'

with open("/tmp/test", "wb") as fp:
    fp.write(txt.encode('utf-8'))
```

result:

```
$ python2 x.py 
$ md5sum /tmp/test
f39cd7554a823b05658d776a27eb97d9  /tmp/test
$ python3 x.py 
$ md5sum /tmp/test
f39cd7554a823b05658d776a27eb97d9  /tmp/test
```